# Can't restart MySQL caused by InnoDB

Tags: mysql, innodb, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I can't restart MySQL or recover MySQL from ( InnoDB tables )

- I have one WSL using Ubuntu 16.04. By "unknown" accident, at morning i can't access MySQL. Tried to restart it and ... all errors.
  Tried with all advice about InnoDB & log* files. But not success.
  I did backup /var/lib/mysql and re-install new instance of WSL - Ubuntu 16.04
- Tried to recover from physical backup files ( log* & data files & database directory ). But still have same errors.

[Update 1]

Follow this guide: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/71596/restoring-mysql-tables-from-ibd-frm-and-mysqllogbin-files

- I have re-installed another WSL
- Follow guide to restore db from .frm & .idb
- Everything goes well until IMPORT TABLESPACE.
  MySQL keep saying :
  `` ERROR 1812 (HY000): Tablespace is missing for table `dbname`.`table` ``

`````
2019-05-16T03:04:36.061132Z mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /var/lib/mysql
2019-05-16T03:04:36.207628Z 0 [Warning] Changed limits: max_open_files: 1024 (requested 5000)
2019-05-16T03:04:36.208347Z 0 [Warning] Changed limits: table_open_cache: 431 (requested 2000)
2019-05-16T03:04:36.472045Z 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
2019-05-16T03:04:36.481592Z 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 5.7.26-0ubuntu0.16.04.1) starting as process 15703 ...
2019-05-16T03:04:36.503219Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: PUNCH HOLE support available
2019-05-16T03:04:36.503655Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
2019-05-16T03:04:36.503712Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2019-05-16T03:04:36.503749Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: GCC builtin __atomic_thread_fence() is used for memory barrier
2019-05-16T03:04:36.503783Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.8
2019-05-16T03:04:36.503823Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
2019-05-16T03:04:36.504677Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2019-05-16T03:04:36.505431Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using CPU crc32 instructions
2019-05-16T03:04:36.521629Z 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Linux Native AIO interface is not supported on this platform. Please check your OS documentation and install appropriate binary of InnoDB.
2019-05-16T03:04:36.521855Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: You can disable Linux Native AIO by setting innodb_use_native_aio = 0 in my.cnf
2019-05-16T03:04:36.521899Z 0 [Warning] InnoDB: Linux Native AIO disabled.
2019-05-16T03:04:36.525155Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 4G, instances = 8, chunk size = 128M
2019-05-16T03:04:37.245621Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2019-05-16T03:04:37.452784Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: page_cleaner coordinator priority: -20
2019-05-16T03:04:37.453044Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: page_cleaner worker priority: -20
2019-05-16T03:04:37.453378Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: page_cleaner worker priority: -20
2019-05-16T03:04:37.453477Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: page_cleaner worker priority: -20
2019-05-16T03:04:37.461387Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2019-05-16T03:04:37.587188Z 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Ignoring the redo log due to missing MLOG_CHECKPOINT between the checkpoint 22709914082 and the end 22709914054.
2019-05-16T03:04:37.587391Z 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Plugin initialization aborted with error Generic error
2019-05-16T03:04:37.890878Z 0 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
2019-05-16T03:04:37.891081Z 0 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
2019-05-16T03:04:37.891128Z 0 [ERROR] Failed to initialize builtin plugins.
2019-05-16T03:04:37.891164Z 0 [ERROR] Aborting

2019-05-16T03:04:37.891207Z 0 [Note] Binlog end
2019-05-16T03:04:37.891332Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'CSV'
2019-05-16T03:04:37.891962Z 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete

2019-05-16T03:04:37.959132Z mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid ended ````
`````

Comment: Have you done anything special in your my.cnf/ini files? Does it look like [bug 85307](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=85307)? With your restore, did you use the [redo logs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-redo-log.html) from the time of backup?

Comment: Actually i have tried with Innodb recovery mode 4 & 6. Nothing special.
For restore not yet tried with redo_logs . Let me try again

Comment: @danblack tried all your suggests but still fail :(

Answer (score 3):

For **[ERROR] InnoDB: Linux Native AIO interface is not supported on this platform. Please check your OS documentation and install appropriate binary of InnoDB.**:
**Solution:**
 Add the following lines at **/etc/mysql/my.cnf**

```
[mysqld]
innodb_use_native_aio = 0
```

For **[ERROR] InnoDB: Ignoring the redo log due to missing MLOG_CHECKPOINT between the checkpoint 92858715 and the end 92858687.**:
**Solution:**
 Delete the ib_logfiles from **/var/lib/mysql**

```
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/mysql/ib_logfile*
```

Comment: The InnoDB redo log (write-ahead log) exists for one purpose: guaranteeing the durability of changes to data files that had been modified since the latest log checkpoint. If you delete the log files (or use `innodb_force_recovery=6`) as a ‘fix’ to this kind of problems, you will likely end up with a database where updates to some data pages were discarded. For example, if an index page was split and only some of the involved pages were written, the index would be corrupted.
Advice like this motivated me to implement https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-27199

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. I was using MySQL in docker but this solution is same for both. You need to remove ib_logfiles
If you are not using docker then

```
rm -rf /var/lib/mysql/ib_logfile*
```

And if you using docker then

```
cd /your_mount_path/
```

then run

```
rm -rf * ib_logfile*
```

**Note: Make sure you make a backup of the data or volume as I ended up losing my data.**

Comment: Actually i have no choice.
- Accept lost database
- Reinstall whole WSL :(

Answer (score 0):

if anyone's ended up here struggling with [wix-embedded-mysql](https://github.com/wix/wix-embedded-mysql) and for some reason can't change the mysql settings in your WSL distro or host unix system, you can just disable it through the [custom mysqld setting](https://github.com/wix/wix-embedded-mysql#customizing-mysqld-settings) `.withServerVariable` like:

```
.withServerVariable("innodb_use_native_aio", 0)
```

That option's only doable if you really don't care about InnoDB usage in your code though.