# Ubuntu 22.04. MariaDB "Starting MariaDB database server mariadbd [fail]"

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, mariadb, innodb

Here's what I use:

```
lsb_release -a
 Distributor ID: Ubuntu
 Description:    Ubuntu 22.04 LTS
 Release:        22.04
 Codename:       jammy

uname -r
 5.10.102.1-microsoft-standard-WSL2
```

```
Operating system
 Windows 11 Pro
  * version
    21H2
  * build 
    22000.708
  * experience
    Windows Feature Experience Pack 1000.22000.708.0.
```

Here are the outputs:

```
sudo mariadb --version
 * mariadb Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.6.7-MariaDB, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 5.2
```

```
sudo service mariadb restart
 * Stopping MariaDB database server mariadbd [ OK ]
 * Starting MariaDB database server [fail]
```

```
sudo service mariadb status
 * MariaDB is stopped.
```

Notice the date in `error.log`, it's some older error. Nothing related to this. I checked the `error.log` on a fresh reinstall, it's empty and still fails to start.

```
nano /var/log/mysql/error.log
 * 2022-03-29 15:43:59 0 [Warning] InnoDB: Linux Native AIO interface is not supported on this platform. Please check your OS documentation and install appropriate binary of InnoDB.
 * 2022-03-29 15:43:59 0 [Warning] InnoDB: Linux Native AIO disabled.
```

```
sudo mysqld --verbose --user root
 * 2022-06-02 13:27:16 0 [Note] mysqld (server 10.6.7-MariaDB-1:10.6.7+maria~focal) starting as process 1445 ...
 * 2022-06-02 13:27:16 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
 * 2022-06-02 13:27:16 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
 * 2022-06-02 13:27:16 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using crc32 + pclmulqdq instructions
 * 2022-06-02 13:27:16 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
 * 2022-06-02 13:27:16 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 4294967296, chunk size = 134217728
 * 2022-06-02 13:27:16 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
 * 2022-06-02 13:27:16 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting crash recovery from checkpoint LSN=10162222816,10254949185
 * 2022-06-02 13:27:16 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Missing FILE_CREATE, FILE_DELETE or FILE_MODIFY before FILE_CHECKPOINT for tablespace 724
 * 2022-06-02 13:27:16 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Plugin initialization aborted with error Data structure corruption
 * 2022-06-02 13:27:16 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
 * 2022-06-02 13:27:17 0 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
 * 2022-06-02 13:27:17 0 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
 * 2022-06-02 13:27:17 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
 * 2022-06-02 13:27:17 0 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB
 * 2022-06-02 13:27:17 0 [ERROR] Aborting
```

The setup has been working without issues for months now. I restarted my PC, had one Windows Update* and now I cannot start the mariadb anymore.

What is this issue and why did it suddenly happen?

---

* If it's relevant, this is the Windows update:

`Update for Windows Security platform - KB5007651 (Version 1.0.2109.27002)`

[Update notes](https://prod.support.services.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/windows-security-update-a6ac7d2e-b1bf-44c0-a028-41720a242da3?preview=true)

---

UPDATE

Just did a complete purge/uninstall of everything Ubuntu and WSL on my system.

Then I did a step-by-step installation as guided here: https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-ubuntu-on-wsl2-on-windows-11-with-gui-support#1-overview

Then I installed the MariaDB `sudo apt install mariadb-server`.

When I do the

`sudo service mariadb start`

I get the [FAIL] again, so it's happening on a fresh installation as well. This time, there are no logs anywhere on the Ubuntu.

For those who asked for the "full crash log"—the two lines in the `error.log` I had was all there was.

For those who asked, here's my `my.cnf`:

```
# The MariaDB configuration file
#
# The MariaDB/MySQL tools read configuration files in the following order:
# 0. "/etc/mysql/my.cnf" symlinks to this file, reason why all the rest is read.
# 1. "/etc/mysql/mariadb.cnf" (this file) to set global defaults,
# 2. "/etc/mysql/conf.d/*.cnf" to set global options.
# 3. "/etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d/*.cnf" to set MariaDB-only options.
# 4. "~/.my.cnf" to set user-specific options.
#
# If the same option is defined multiple times, the last one will apply.
#
# One can use all long options that the program supports.
# Run program with --help to get a list of available options and with
# --print-defaults to see which it would actually understand and use.
#
# If you are new to MariaDB, check out https://mariadb.com/kb/en/basic-mariadb-articles/

#
# This group is read both by the client and the server
# use it for options that affect everything
#
[client-server]
# Port or socket location where to connect
# port = 3306
socket = /run/mysqld/mysqld.sock

# Import all .cnf files from configuration directory
!includedir /etc/mysql/conf.d/
!includedir /etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d/
```

---

UPDATE#2

I have posted an answer of what worked. In short, this is WSL issue.

Comment: Looks like an [aysnchronous IO](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/innodb-system-variables/#innodb_use_native_aio) support problem. Why it changed after Windows Update, I don't know. Production database on MariaDB / WSL? Sketchy idea.

Comment: This answer might be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61889117/973254

Comment: @O.Jones this is not a production setting, it's development.

Comment: @user973254 adding that setting did not change anything.

Comment: Let's see the config file(s) for MariaDB.  Especially any changes you made.  How much RAM do you have?  From one log entry, I assume it is at least 6GB.

Comment: Eh?  I don't understand -- You mentioned Ubuntu and Windows??

Comment: The fun new world of [WSL(1,2)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/about), and all its fun as an intermediary between linux and windows. [what](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/8443) [could](https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-28580), [go wrong](https://github.com/MariaDB/mariadb-docker/issues/403)? [dup question](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/ubuntu-2204-starting-mariadb-database-server-mariadbd-fail/) without seeing the full log doesn't fully answer it. You server includes a crash recovery, what are the logs for what happened on the last shutdown (presumably before reboot)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My brother has found a github issue with Ubuntu WSL that produced the same AIO error with MySQL.

Here is what worked for me:

```
sudo apt remove --purge *mysql*
sudo apt remove --purge *mariadb*
sudo rm -rf /etc/mysql /var/lib/mysql
sudo apt autoremove
sudo apt autoclean
```

Notice my edit in the OP that I did a complete reinstall of WSL and Ubuntu, so it kept happening on the fresh install as well.

Also notice that this completely purged every data I had.

In short, this is WSL issue, not an issue with MariaDB.

---

The issue on github:

- https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/3631#issuecomment-1145856044

Comment: The failed recovery is [MDEV-28870](https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-28870) fixed in 10.6.9 ([not yet released](https://ci.mariadb.org/26524/) packages for testing). The crash during ddl/dml could be a crash due to the DDL `alter table` or similar triggering [WSL issue 8443](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/8443)

Answer (score 1):

The messages indicate that the `libaio` interface (as opposed to the newer `io_uring`) is being used. In that interface, at least on the plain Linux kernel, the `io_setup()` system call may fail, causing a fallback to the simulated asynchronous I/O (`innodb_use_native_aio=0`).

The recovery failure may be explained by a bug [MDEV-28731](https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-28731) that was introduced by [MDEV-12353](https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-12353) in MariaDB Server 10.5.